# License app instead of 2 copied apps (light and pro)

Tags: android, apk, visibility, license-key

I would like to have 2 version of my app in Android : light version and pro version.
The light version is the same than the light with fewer features.

Instead of constantly copy my source code in two git for each changes, I would like to have all my code in the light version and the pro version will be like a "license-APK".

I have see the app CamScanner ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.camscanner ) with license ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.lic.camscanner ) so I think it's possible.
The only problem is when I install the two versions of camscanner, I have 2 icons (camscanner and camscanner license visible).

So my questions are :
 - How can I create a license APK ?
 - How to make invisible the license APK (in the list of the apps)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App Purchase with verification. And disable the pro features in the code when verification failed.

Comment: Thanks but if the user change his smartphone, what happen ?

Comment: @Jéwôm' you can restore the purchase from Google Play using licensing API.

Answer (score 0):

As m.ding said you have to either use In-App Purchases with a verification and simply check if they have those features or create another version. Lite and Pro.
I would highly recommend the second technique since it will keep your code neater and is overall a cleaner solution. :)